# ImageMagick convert for loop

Tags: for-loop, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I would like to iterate this code over a directory of files:

```
convert Film_Crew.jpg -resize 1920x1080 -size 1920x1080 xc:black +swap -gravity center -composite Film_Crew_resize.jpg
```

Images in my directory:

Film_Crew.jpg

Film_Crew copy.jpg

Film_Crew copy 2.jpg

Film_Crew copy 3.jpg

Film_Crew copy 4.jpg

Film_Crew copy 5.jpg

Film_Crew copy 6.jpg

I tried to use this code because it worked for me last time I tried, but it isn't working now.

```
for i in *.*; do convert $i -auto-orient -resize 1920x1080 -size 1920x1080 xc:black +swap -gravity center -composite "new/${i%.*}.jpg";done
```

I am on a Mac working in Terminal. The error I get is this:

convert: unable to open image `Film_Crew': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: unable to open image `copy': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: unable to open image `2.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no such image`black' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageList/8770.
convert: no images defined `new/Film_Crew copy 2.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
convert: unable to open image`Film_Crew': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: unable to open image`copy': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: unable to open image`3.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no such image `black' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageList/8770.
convert: no images defined`new/Film_Crew copy 3.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
convert: unable to open image `Film_Crew': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: unable to open image `copy': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: unable to open image `4.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no such image`black' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageList/8770.
convert: no images defined `new/Film_Crew copy 4.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
convert: unable to open image`Film_Crew': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: unable to open image`copy': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: unable to open image`5.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no such image `black' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageList/8770.
convert: no images defined`new/Film_Crew copy 5.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
convert: unable to open image `Film_Crew': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: unable to open image `copy': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format`' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: unable to open image `6.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no such image`black' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageList/8770.
convert: no images defined `new/Film_Crew copy 6.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
convert: unable to open image`Film_Crew': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: unable to open image`copy.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert: no such image `black' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageList/8770.
convert: no images defined`new/Film_Crew copy.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
convert: unable to open image `new/Film_Crew.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.

Comment: Your command works fine for me in ImageMagick 6.9.9.3 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra. What is your version of ImageMagick? If IM 7, then change convert to magick. Are you sure your file, Film_Crew.jpg exists in the location you expect? Is it corrupt? You can also do the same for a given directory using mogrify and -draw and the appropriate compose method. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify_compose

Comment: How do I check which version of ImageMagick I have?
edit: Found it. I am on ImageMagick 6.9.7-7 Q16. I am sure Film_Crew.jpg exists in the folder I am in and it is not corrupt. I will look into mogrify documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Try convert -version or magick -version. If that fails, then type -a convert or type -a magick

Comment: You have files with spaces in the name, such as, **new/Film_Crew copy 2.jpg**. The filenames will be truncated at the first space in your wild card search and list. Thus ImageMagick will not find that file, since it is missing the suffix, etc. Put double quotes about your filename commands. Or remove those extra copies that exist in that directory.

Comment: That's true! Thanks. Do I need to add double quotes around something in my code to fix that?

Comment: Try "$I". That seems to work for me

Comment: I changed my code to this: `for i in *.*; do convert "$i" -auto-orient -resize 1920x1080 -size 1920x1080 xc:black +swap -gravity center -composite "new/${i%.*}.jpg";done. `I get significantly less errors but it still doesn't work. One of the errors looks like this convert: unable to open image `new/Film_Crew copy 2.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.

Comment: Edit your post and show a list of at least the top 10 images in your directory. You can get that from "ls *"

Comment: When trying that I got this: `ls: *.-: No such file or directory`

Comment: Change directories to your input directory. Then just use ls * without any hyphen. I do not know why the hyphen got added by stack overflow.

Comment: I tried a similar command and it works just fine for me. What is your version of OSX. Try rebooting your computer and try again.

Comment: I am on OS 10.12.6. Rebooted with no luck.

Comment: Are you sure it is 10.12.6. My Sierra is 10.12.5. I am unaware of a newer OSX. Are you using a bash terminal window or some other shell window?

Comment: If you are still having problems, try running `ls -l | pbcopy` and clicking `edit` under your question and pasting (`Cmd+V`).

Comment: Likewise with `identify *jpg | pbcopy` and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Life would be easier with `mogrify` - no `for` loop, no quoting:

```
mkdir new
mogrify -path new -resize 1920x1080 -background black -gravity center -extent 1920x1080 *jpg
```

Comment: Yes, mogrify with -extent is better than my suggestion of mogrify with -draw. But it is odd that his command works fine for me.

Comment: The `*.*` glob is horribly Windows-y and should probably be `*jpg`. The `$i` should be double-quoted. The parameter substitution is probably not very robust.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Mark S. I usually use `*.jpg`, but I left his `*.*` to see if it works. *.* can catch non-image files. It could be an issue of the version of OSX and what level of bash exists. But I find it unlikely that it would suddenly stop unless there was a change of ImageMagick versions or OSX. That is why I suggested a reboot. But the mogrify is so simple and probably the best method, unless multiple images are needed in the command or parenthesis processing.

Comment: In terminal I changed directory to my folder with those files and ran the exact mogrify code above in your answer. I got this error: `mogrify: unable to open image `new/Film_Crew copy 2.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.`

Comment: Mark's mogrify command works for me to create the new images although I get an error "mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504."  Does your new directory already exist? ImageMagick will not create it for you.

Comment: My new directory did not already exist! Running `mkdir new` fixed the problem and my original code worked flawlessly. I thought last time I used this that ImageMagick created the directory for me, but now I know it won't do that. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Try this using ImageMagick assuming all your input images are JPG. I set the Internal Field Specifier to a new line, so that spaces in the filenames are considered part of the name.

```
cd
cd path2/your_image_directory
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
list=`ls *.jpg`
for img in $list; do 
convert \( "$img" -auto-orient -resize 1920x1080 \) \( -size 1920x1080 xc:black \) +swap -gravity center -composite "./new/${img%.*}.jpg"
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```